# Saving unicode characters in R

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

I have svg file that I get from dataURI (plotly.js) and sending that data to server (shiny app):

```
    exportImage(plot, settings.config).then(function(dataURI) {
      var payload;
      if (!settings.dataURI) {
        var data = dataURI.replace(/data:image\/svg\+xml,/, '');
        // I'm using decodeURIComponent in browser because it's much faster.
        payload = decodeURIComponent(data);
        $('<div>' + payload + '</div>').appendTo('body');
      } else {
        payload = dataURI;
      }
      Shiny.onInputChange(settings.messageId, payload);
    });
```

The svg contain unicode characters in unit `mm³`, and in observeEvent the svg contain proper characters, when I pause in RStudio with browser(), I've got this:

```
> substring(input$svg, 198036, 198061)
[1] "Volume (mm³) on log2 scale"
```

But when I save that into a file I've got `mm3`, I'm using this:

```
writeLines(
  paste('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', input$svg),
  svg.file
)
```

I've tried using enc2utf8 function and setting useBytes to TRUE, I've also tried to add `<?xml` in JavaScript and using `cat(svg, svg.file)` and it produce characters with invalid encoding or 3 instead of ³.

I've got this:

```
> Encoding(input$svg)
[1] "UTF-8"
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250;LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250;LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250"
```

Should this be UT8 for it to work? How can I save utf8 characters to file in R?

I'm testing this on Windows but it will be deployed to Linux machine.

Comment: Try using "UTF-16", I am not sure, but it returned correctly on my machine, there might be other reasons

Comment: @PKumar did you test this on windows?

Comment: yes, so if I use Ecoding(x) <- "UTF-8" , it throws some weird character but when I use , "UTF-16" it throws me mm^3 as you have mentioned, but I believe there can other things like locale settings is involved. You may check a function if you are only interested in printing is `stringi::stri_trans_general`. Not sure if any of these help and of-course this is interesting problem, I am just trying to help. Thanks

Comment: @PKumar it works with UTF-16, you can add this as an answer, it may be helpful to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems the problem is with the encoding ,  In this case if I change the encoding to UTF-16 then the value is correctly printed.

So in this case :

```
Encoding(input$svg) <- "UTF-16"
```

The above works well and prints the correct output

```
#[1] "Volume (mm³) on log2 scale"
```

[image]